# How to increase the brightness of images in appcelerator?

Tags: image, appcelerator, opacity, brightness, appcelerator-titanium

I am developing an ios app,In that I have requirement To provide the brightness to the images.So Using opacity i am providing the brightness. I put opacity maximum   value 1 Still i am not happy with that brightness Is their any way to increase the brightness of the images?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Image Filters](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/2089#!overview) module to adjust image brightness, contrast and saturation

Comment: Thank you for giving the reply. I want free module .can you share it